# Does get(int index) method of List return a reference to the original object or a new object from given index

Tags: java

I am a freshman learning Java recently. I encountered a problem when using the method get of List in Java.

I am confused of how it works.
Is the object returned by the method created via **new** or just a reference to the original object in the list?

My code is as follows:

```
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfos = am.getRunningTasks(2);
    ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo currentTaskInfo = taskInfos.get(0);
    am.getRunningTasks(2).get(0).description = "value"; 
    Toast.makeText(this,am.getRunningTasks(2).get(0).description, 10).show();
```

I want to look for a variable which I can modify and set as the identifier for a running task. But it seems I cannot modify the description. Toast shows the description is still **null**, not **value**.

Comment: You should download JDK code and look into it to build the right knowledge

Comment: A reference to the original object in the list for standard `List` implementations.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29

Comment: @JunedAhsan Yes, I have tried it, but the network condition is so poor that I cannot connect to the website, so I came here for help in emergency.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera Yes,thx, but I have read it and found no answers on that.

Comment: I have answered you. I'd like you put some effort before you post on SO.

Comment: Just HOW would it create an new object? What args would it pass to a constructor? A List would have to have knowledge of the class of objects it was holding, which is contrary to the entire philosophy of the Collections API. Or do you mean a call to `clone()`? A "CloningList" might be workable.

Comment: modified the title to reflect your *actual* question.

Comment: Have solved it, it return by reference, thx!

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't create a new object. It returns the reference to it.

Comment: This should be a comment than an answer.

Comment: Really?But why can't I modify the members inside the object it returns?

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera When it answers the question, no matter how short it is.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera, why should this be a comment? Although short, it does answer the OP's question. The part about doing some beginners tutorial was indeed a comment (which I removed), but the rest of it is an answer to the question.

Comment: Instead of making comments that doesn't answer the Op's question, I believe this kind of answering is better.

Comment: @laosiaudi Try it. Post a question or edit current post with your code example.

Comment: Yeah, Suresh is right. You need to show us what have you tried and where are you stuck?